# Laravel 4 Query Cache

Tags: php, caching, laravel, eloquent

I'm having trouble getting my queries to cache. Anytime I hit my API I am getting fresh results from the DB instead of the Cached results that im going for. The odd thing is if I look in the file cache I can see the cached results and they are exactly what im expecting, yet when I call the API I get fresh results. Below are some snippets of the relevant files. Where am I going wrong here?

Repository Function my API calls:

```
public function topMonth()
{
    $top = $this->repository->month()->top()->joinUser()->remember(30)->get(['things.id', 'things.votes', 'things.title', 'things.description', 'things.tags', 'things.created_at', 'users.id as user_id','users.username','users.picture as user_picture'])->toArray();

    return $top;
}
```

Model

```
class Thing extends Eloquent
{

public function scopeTop($query)
{
    return $query->orderBy('things.votes', 'desc');
}

public function scopeYear($query)
{
    return $query->whereRaw("things.created_at > STR_TO_DATE('" . Carbon::now()->subYear() . "', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')");
}

public function scopeMonth($query)
{
    return $query->whereRaw("things.created_at > STR_TO_DATE('" . Carbon::now()->subMonth() . "', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')");
}

public function scopeWeek($query)
{
    return $query->whereRaw("things.created_at > STR_TO_DATE('" . Carbon::now()->subWeek() . "', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')");
}

public function scopeDay($query)
{
    return $query->whereRaw("things.created_at > STR_TO_DATE('" . Carbon::now()->subDay() . "', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')");
}

public function scopeJoinUser($query)
{
    return $query->join('users', function($join)
        {
            $join->on('users.id', '=', 'things.created_by');
        });
}

}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You will only be able to cache like that if your sql query stays exactly the same. In this instance, it won't due to your `top()` query scope.

This is due to the way in which the query builder generates a cache key. It converts the whole  query into an sql and serializes it's bindings, as obsered in the Laravel code below:

```
/**
 * Generate the unique cache key for the query.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function generateCacheKey()
{
    $name = $this->connection->getName();

    return md5($name.$this->toSql().serialize($this->bindings));
}
```

Instead, you will have to manually cache this like so;

```
if (($top = Cache::get('users.top')) === null)
{
    $top = $this->repository->month()->top()->joinUser()->get(['things.id', 'things.votes', 'things.title', 'things.description', 'things.tags', 'things.created_at', 'users.id as user_id','users.username','users.picture as user_picture'])->toArray();
    Cache::put('users.top', $top, 30);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for not just giving an answer but explaining why it is how it is. You are a gentleman and scholar!